# Is it grammatically correct - "Her and her looney boyfriend nicked my truck of cigarettes and drove it in the river."

Tags: subjects, verb-agreement

Is it grammatically correct - "**Her** and her looney boyfriend nicked my truck of cigarettes and drove it into the river. Just for a laugh."

Is that first word 'Her' as a subject grammatically correct? and if yes, then what grammar rule is used? It will be helpful if you tell me the term of that grammar rule so that i can search and learn further.

The given sentence is used in the animated movie Batman: Assault on Arkham at 17:02 time.

Comment: It would be less jarring if the initial "her" were changed to "she" and "in" changed to "into". But it would also presumably be less "authentic" or representative of the speaking character.

Comment: Oh! yes, 'into' is there in place of 'in'. It's my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: But 'Her and her boyfriend' feels more correct than 'she and her boyfriend'.

Comment: Forget the boyfriend for a moment: "*Her* nicked my truck and drove it into the river?"? Nope.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But english is all about different situation/sentence, different rule. Her nicked.....' is wrong but 'Her and her boyfriend nicked....' might be right. I do not know. I want some proper answer.

Comment: Hence my comment about it being presumably "less authentic" for the character in question. But I can tell you I, as a native speaker, would never phrase it "Her and her boyfriend nicked...", and I wouldn't expect anyone I know to do so, though I wouldn't be particularly scandalized if someone did.

Comment: As far as i know, people who make dialogue in any movie or book are very serious about grammar used in the dialogue.

Comment: and minor mistakes are definitely going to scandalize my examiner who will check my answer sheet. They ask very minor grammar mistakes in the sentences.

Comment: I think you have perhaps a overly idealized view :) There are few people who are "serious" about grammar, and many (!) fewer who are informed enough for that seriousness to mean anything. At best, the writers are trying to emulate the speech of a certain class of character they have some experience with (even if it's second-hand experience), but that's all it is: emulation. Screenwriters do not study languages or dialects, they employ them. Sometimes they even employ ham-fisted shortcuts to "mark" a character as "lower class", believe it or not.

Comment: "Her" is incorrect, according to the usual rules of English grammar, plus it leaves one wondering how you create a "truck of cigarettes".  Do you use full cartons or glue individual cigarettes together?  (But, of course, it's a movie, and the speaker is presumably not supposed to be literate.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, screenwriters do not bother for studying languages but grammarians do. I am not sure but i think every line in any movie or book must be first checked by some grammarians.

Comment: @user132262 You may wish to think that, but it ain't so ;)

Comment: I consider "she and her boyfriend" to be more grammatical, but "her and her boyfriend" is used frequently (I would never write that, though, not on purpose anyway). That's not what really gave me pause though, that would be "nicked my truck of cigarettes". It seems the "of" is functioning like it does in "he robbed me of my dignity", but doing the same with "nick" sounds very odd to me.

Comment: Looking at a transcript of the movie, it looks like the line is actually "Her and her loony boyfriend _lit my truck a cigarette_ and drove it into the river". Not that I have any idea what that means. Maybe something to do with a "final cigarette" before one's death? I don't know what smoking-related tropes are out there.

Comment: I was kind of hoping that someone would argue in favor of "She and she looney boyfriend nicked my truck of cigarettes and drove it into the river. Just for a laugh." But evidently most people here consider it ungrammatical or sub-substandard, or something.

Comment: @DanBron, Here, is it that 'being serious about grammar' is the problem, or 'wrongly using language/grammar'? My experience in India with those speaking against grammar is that most of them do not know it.  Without grammar how will one point out when the usage goes wrong...?

Answer (score 3):

**Her and her boyfriend** used as the compound subject of a verb is "substandard" though not uncommon.

The grammar rule is that subjects are normally in the nominative case (she) not the objective case (her).

We don't say "Him likes bacon" or "Her likes bacon" but "He likes bacon" and "She likes bacon".

The fact that the subject is compound should not change the case of the third person pronoun from **she** to **her**.

Speakers also make the other mistake, using the nominative when they should use the objective:

*Bill came along with her and I to the movies.

*Finding an apartment in our price range is difficult for my girlfriend and I.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know in which idiolects the objective case is more acceptable, would you?

Comment: It's widespread, for sure, not a feature of a (geographic) dialect. I'd say it's a sociolect feature, probably hinging on the education level of the speaker's parents.

Comment: @Dan Bron: English is a living language - when enough people are wrong, they are right. I often feel that, as there are no "rules" in English, "correct" is never a good adjective to use, and your "appropriate" allows for a normal use. The use of what is not the objective but the disjunctive or demonstrative (actually, the dative) has been in common use for centuries. It seems to have connections to the use of "moi" and "lui" in French.

Answer (score 1):

In his well known 1964 article *Negation in English*, Edward Klima characterized the use of the subject forms in contemporary English this way: the subject form is used for the unconjoined subject of an explicit finite verb, but otherwise the object forms are used.  And I think that's right.  Of course, there is an old-fashioned archaic style in which you'd use "she" instead of "her".  Your example sentence sounds fine to me, but if you wanted to sound stuffy, you'd use "she".

Answer (score 0):

It occurs frequently in vernacular English, it is by many authorities considered to be inappropriate for formal English.

Even though it does occur in vernacular English, I'd say that there is hardly ever a good reason to not use “she”, as the subject pronoun will be accepted by all speakers, but some speakers reject the object pronoun, and almost no speaker would consider it pompous unlike with, say, “It was she.” opposed to “It was her.” which would be considered pompous by a certain number of speakers, though some speakers would also consider “It was her.” to be incorrect, however common.

A good reason to use “her” would be in fiction, to accurately portray vernacular language.